# How can I properly load A page or A div automatically?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I'm creating A simple queuing system, right now when ever I click my button called `BtnNxt()` it will dequeue my enqueued data and render it to my page. and it also render from another page. which is my call screen page, but when I click it again my call screen page needs to be refresh to update the current number from my queue. so what I want is , Ithink i need to refresh my page or maybe my div to update it?

Here is my `BtnNext()` controller :

```
   public ActionResult BtnNext()
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
        var first = MyQueue.todayQueue.Dequeue();
        MyQueue.todayQueue.Count();
        TempData["QueueItem"] = first;
        TempData.Keep();
        return PartialView("_queuenumber");
    }
```

and here is my callscreen page:

```
@{
    var item = (Rosh.QueueMe.Web.Models.MyQueue)TempData["QueueItem"];
}
<table>
    <tr>
        <th scope="tickets">TICKETS</th>
        <th scope="name">NAME</th>
        <th scope="counter">COUNTER</th>
        <th scope="service">SERVICE</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="data">
        <td>#@item.QueueNumber</td>
        <td>@item.Name</td>
        <td>Desk 1</td>
        <td>@item.ServiceId</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I tried to use this code

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1" />
```

this code refresh my page every 1 sec, but is it possible to just reload the div? maybe using ajax?

Comment: use Partial view and Ajax, when data come back then replace div content.

Comment: my `BtnNext()` function is already using ajax and partial view, because im rendering the current data on my page, I need to render that data again from another page.

Answer (score 0):

use asyn keyword both side server & client, add the spinner loaders to each and every div which you want to make automatically load. don't make any custom tread because sometime thread take more time but actually he didn't need more time for sleep, so best solution is make every controller ayns and caller must be asyn as well.

Comment: are you using the asp.net core or asp.net mvc ?

Comment: https://srramalho.wordpress.com/2017/08/27/asp-net-mvc-loading-partial-views-asynchronously/

I hope above url will help you out from you staff.

Comment: i'm using Asp.net MVC

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        setInterval(loadData,1000);  // invoke load every second
        loadData(); // load on initial page loaded
    });

    function loadData() {
        $('#Div').load( '/controller/BtnNext' );
    }
</script>
```

Comment: can you explain me this?

Comment: The function is called once all the DOM elements of the page are ready to be used.For each second the div element will get updated by calling respective action method.

Comment: i'm getting my data of my Call Screen in my `TempData["QueueItem"]` , I tried it it doesnt work